# Connecting Google Glass to a computer

Tags: android, adb, google-glass, google-gdk, android-sdk-tools

I hope someone can help me cause I can't understand what my problem is.
The thing is I'm trying to connect my Google Glass to my computer (Windows 7HP 64bit SP1), but *adb* - with the Debug Mode ON on the Glass, of course - can't recognize the item in its attached devices.
I followed various instructions I googled about this matter, but it doesn't work even if everything seems ok to me.
I installed the Google USB Driver, the Panel Control "Device Manager" sees the Glass as an Android Device, as you can see from the images below.

[image: Drivers details] [image: Hardware ID]

Beside that, I downloaded the *Android SDK* (version "*adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702*") with the last versions of these packages: Android SDK Tools, Platform-Tools, Build-Tools, API 21, API 20, API 19, API 15, Android Support Repository, Library, Google Play Services, Repository, Google USB drivers (of course) and Google Web driver.
Do you think is there something wrong with my configuration? If not, what can I do to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your responses.
Have a nice day you all!

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debug-enabled Android smartphone to your computer? Does it show when you run `adb devices`?

Answer (score 0):

The poster to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112201/google-glass-on-windows7-cannot-access-device) was able to solve this issue by completely uninstalling and then re-installing the driver. The previous driver has to be removed.