# Google Glass on Windows7: cannot access device

Tags: android, windows, adb, google-glass

I have a brand new google glass and I tried to connect it to my Windows 7 PCs, but I cannot access the storage. If try the command `adb devices`, glass is not listed.

- I already installed the latest Google USB Drivers.
- Enabled Developer settings on Glass
- Glass is listed as "Android ADB Interface" in the Device Manager.
- If i connect glass to a Windows8 PC, everything looks good - so there shouldn't be problems with the cable or glass itself.
- I also tested to update the drivers INF file with the data listed in the device manager at "hardware ID" (as found in several solutions), but that didnt change anything.

I tested all these steps on two differnts PCs.

Comment: This belongs on the android stack exchange - also you have this tagged as aero-glass?  Even if this was on topic for here (which it isn't), it's still tagged incorrectly.

Comment: sorry about the aero-glass - first time i write on stackoverflow ... but i think i fixed it

Comment: @user4288741 try http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user4288741 try to uninstall the driver first. If a previous version of the driver was installed, the glass won't be detected until you uninstall/re-install it.

Comment: thanks, complete uninstall solved the problem, i only tried updating without deleting the old one

Answer (score 0):

Answer as originally posted as edit to the "question" (by @user4288741 ):

> Driver completely uninstalled and then reinstalled latest driver -
>   everything works fine now.